# Set variable to zero javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set my variables to numeric zero, and count based 
on IF statements.  However, when I run the code below, ChangeOver is instantly picked up as 1, engaging the 3rd IF statement, throwing everything else off.  How can I start the count for each variable at 0 and have the IF statements count accordingly?

```
function clearX() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var BlankStart = 0;
  var CountX = 0;
  var NewBlanks = 0;
  var ChangeOver = 0;

  for (var i=5;i<10;i++) {
    var AValue = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();

    if ((BlankStart > 1) && (CountX > 3)) {    //If initital blanks and more than 3 X's identified, next blanks are new blanks (FlipBlank)
      ChangeOver = 1;
    }
    if ((AValue === "") && (ChangeOver = 0)) {  //If Col A is blank and less than 3 X's encountered yet (FlipBlank) 
      BlankStart = BlankStart + 1;
    }
    if ((AValue === "") && (ChangeOver = 1)) {  //If Col A is blank after 3 or more X's (FlipBlank), start new blanks
      NewBlanks = NewBlanks + 1;
    }
    if (AValue === "X") {  //If Col A = 'X' 
      CountX = CountX + 1;
    }
    sheet.getRange(i,17).setValue(BlankStart);
    sheet.getRange(i,18).setValue(CountX); 
    sheet.getRange(i,19).setValue(ChangeOver);    
    sheet.getRange(i,20).setValue(NewBlanks);  
  }                         

}
```

Comment: Your statement is somewhat unclear -- can you rewrite some of your question?

Comment: can you check why assignment operator is here instead comparison 
if ((AValue === "") && (ChangeOver = 0))
if ((AValue === "") && (ChangeOver = 1))

Comment: This has been solved.  I just needed to to change "= 0" to "===0" in my IF statements.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *entirely* clear on your question, but if I were to take a guess you mistyped your predicate:

```js
function clearX() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var BlankStart = 0, CountX = 0, NewBlanks = 0;
  var ChangeOver = 0;

  for (let i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    let AValue = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();

    if (BlankStart > 1 && CountX > 3)    //If initital blanks and more than 3 X's identified, next blanks are new blanks (FlipBlank)
      ChangeOver = 1;

    if (AValue && ChangeOver === 0)  //If Col A is blank and less than 3 X's encountered yet (FlipBlank) 
      BlankStart++;

    if (AValue && ChangeOver === 1)  // If Col A is blank after 3 or more X's (FlipBlank), start new blanks
      NewBlanks++;

    if (AValue === "X")  // If Col A = 'X' 
      CountX++;

    sheet.getRange(i,17).setValue(BlankStart);
    sheet.getRange(i,18).setValue(CountX); 
    sheet.getRange(i,19).setValue(ChangeOver);    
    sheet.getRange(i,20).setValue(NewBlanks);  
  }                         

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved.  I just needed to to change "= 0" to "=== 0" in my IF statements.  Thanks!